# what is the good hash function for given situation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, hashmap, hashtable

There is a points given in two dimensional plane and I want to count maximum collinear points for that I calculated all possible lines slopes and their intercepts.
To solve this problem, I tried to build a hash table but i am unable to find a hash function by which I can easily point all collinear points in one hash key. So help me to find out hash function that fits for this scenario?

Comment: You want to hash each point to an int such that it will give you the colinearity with any other point ? That doesn't seem possible. Maybe your question isn't perfectly clear.

Comment: I calculate all possible lines simply by using every two points and for that I calculate slope and their intercept. And if for any two lines their slopes and intercepts are same, I can say that these points are collinear.

Comment: yes, but see my answer. You cannot relate the points because that would create some unwanted transitivity. See my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible, because colinearity is not transitive. I.e., lets say A B and C lie on a line (i.e. are colinear). Therefore, A B and C should get the same hash key. Next, C D and E also lie on another line. Therefore, C D and E should also get the same hash key. Consequently, A B receive the same hash key as D and E, which is wrong because these points are not colinear.

In addition, colinearity is defined on sets of points, so my above definition is rather vague. I.e. you cannot say A and B are colinear (well, you can, but if you only regard two points, each pair of points is colinear).

What you can do is save **the sets of colinear points** in a hash map. Then, a good hash function would simply consist of the slope s and ordinate intercept i. For example, you could use s * 31i. This hash map can be used to add new points to the sets and finally count the size of the sets to retrieve your answer.

Comment: THen give me any other method so that I can calculate maximum number of collinear points.

Comment: +1 for coping with the *give me teh code* attitude, you're brave.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could consider an algorithm based on the [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).
Hough transform allows you to detect lines in an image by counting the number of points falling in a line with a given slope and intercept (or angle and distance of the line from the origin).
So, in your specific case, you could store the votes for each distance/angle pairs in a two-dimensional matrix and later take the maximum value from this matrix. This would give you the maximum number of co-linear points.
If you allow for approximations then, instead of looking for a single value, you could find a small rectangular grid providing maximum sum of value.